# Using Go with fish fish shell - error when running `go install /path/to/src`

Tags: go, fish

I am following the "How to Write Code" portion of the golang docs, [here](http://golang.org/doc/code.html). I am also using fish fish shell.

I have followed the tutorial and set the proper environment variables (GOPATH and PATH) but I can't get the command `go install github.com/user/hello` to work with my installation.
I am getting an error:

> can't load package: package github.com/user/hello: import
>   "github.com/user/hello": cannot find package

Comment: You know it now, but for future reference: `go env` on the command line prints the Go-related environment settings.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you topskip. I knew about `go env` and used it to inspect my environment variables, but `GOPATH` was not showing up there, though it was set in my config.fish.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had, in fact, incorrectly set my environment variables.
Specifically, when setting GOPATH in my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file I needed to export the variable.

Put these lines in your config.fish for fish shell to use Go:
`set -x GOPATH $HOME/path/to/your/workspace`

Note the **-x**. That was what was missing.

Answer (score 4):

Even better than editing the config.fish file, run `set` command with `--universal` (to persist) and `-x` (export) in your shell like so:

```
set --universal -x GOPATH $HOME/path/to/goworkspace
```